# Windows Git Bash does not recognize commands in PHP exec

Tags: php, windows, cmd, exec, git-bash

I have a simple test PHP file:

```
<?php echo exec('php -v');
```

When I execute **php -v** in Git Bash, the console displays:

> PHP 5.6.3 (cli) (built: Nov 12 2014 17:18:08)
>
> Copyright (c) 1997-20147 The PHP Group
>
> Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

But, when I execute **php test.php** the console displays:

> ‘php’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

If I execute **php test.php** in cmd.exe this works and displays:

> Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

*Note: I have Windows 8.1 and Git Bash 2.7.1.2*

**SOLVED**

I had deleted folders in my PATH var, this isn't a problem for cmd.exe but, in Git Bash I don't know why doesn't work.

I deleted the deleted paths from PATH and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Re-install Git, and make sure to tick the **Run Git from the Windows command prompt** option.

Also, if Git is freshly installed, you might need to restart your PC for the new PATH variable to be recognized (the way "php" is globally recognized rather than setting a path to the php actual executable).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, I did it and I have the same problem. If I execute the command in Git Bash I got that error (php -v works but when I call the script 'php test.php' fails), if I execute the command in cmd.exe that's works.

Comment: Well, if "php" works, then the PATH is fine. Weird. I will subscribe to this question and look for the answer too. Interesting. Good luck!

Comment: I solved this, I had deleted folders in my PATH var, this isn't a problem for cmd.exe but, in Git Bash I don't know why doesn't work. I deleted the deleted paths from PATH and it works.